# How to fire alarm at exact current time when I click

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to fire my alarm on the current time when I click, with interval of 5 min, where my alarm is not firing when I am clicking rather it was playing after some time interval.

**Example:** My pending intent was set at 12:55:03 and my first alarm was fired at 12:55:11,12:56:11,12:57,11. Couldn't understand the behavior.

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 5*60*60, pi);
```

It's my first attempt at Alarm Manager concept.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!